# Convert Timestamp into the Date for the Community Connector

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, looker-studio

I have been working on a community connector. I have connected my API and I am getting the date in timestamp format what I wanna do is to convert that timestamp into the date Format for the Community Connector dimension. I have tried it through the formula thing but it's not working.

API snippet timestamp screenshot has been attached which I wanna convert. I'm trying this
[image]
`

```
  
fields.newDimension()
  .setId('created_at')
  .setName('Created At')
  .setDescription('Timestamp as a date.')
  .setFormula("TODATE($timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', '%Y%m%d')")
  .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY)
```

`

I want a formulat that can convert the Timestamp into the YEAR_MONTH_DAY while adding my fields.

Comment: Have you tried the Date() constructor?

Comment: Nope can you please specify some more explanation